Excel File handling feature gets unresponsive after few days usage of the web app
We have a web app in AWS EC2 (t3.large) with a feature that lets users upload Excel files from the web UI (compress and store files in an S3 bucket) and later on, shows the data in Excel in a web view and lets users edit that data. In the beginning worked fine but recently with more usage of the web app, After 2-3 days of app usage by our users this feature became unresponsive(no errors we can see) and the node server lost the ability to read/write these Excel files anymore.
We assume the problem is from either of these 4 aspects or something we did not think of

AWS SDK - Based on this article https://medium.com/@andyhu92/interesting-story-about-how-we-solved-a-socket-hang-up-issue-in-aws-lambda-cd467a6febca) we assumed the issue was this as we had multiple places in multiple apps using different AWS SDK versions and didn't know it was a global instance. We updated all the plugins and ensured the same config exists in all places but unfortunately didn't fix it.

Sheet JS Excel file reading([https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx][2]) - The plugin could have some flows where it stops working after a certain amount of usage. But we changed this plugin and checked again with another plugin still the issue is there.

7zip file compressing/decompressing([https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-7z][3]) - Using the file system we compress and decompress. We removed this compression and tried again the issue was still there.

EC2 instance gets unresponsive after a certain amount of usage (2-3 days) of file handling But the server is responsive, with no excessive heap we can see, and memory usage is shown as not excessive usage (Cloudwatch dashboard and PM2 monit), and all other APIs of the same server are fully responsive except for the file handling related endpoints.


We added openTelemetry to find the issue but we didn't see any failed requests or errors except the file view requests are unresponsive and never load the response (We have a very long timeout in our AWS load balancer). But all other requests/features work fine as usual. Also, we cannot find a way to recreate this situation locally or on our own.
Does someone have similar experiences or can someone direct us on how we should approach/debug this to get it resolved?
Update:
According to the below stats in pm2 monit (As I remember at 8.31 am I restarted the express/graphQL server and then it started to work again, always this trick works)
[![pm2 monit stats][4]][4]
)
[2]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx
[3]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-7z
[4]: https://i.sstatic.net/V06aafst.png

What are the CPU levels of that EC2 instance? You are using a Burstable performance instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud that is great for bursty workloads, but not great if it has a continual high load. You can monitor the CPU, perhaps turn on Unlimited Mode (extra charges apply) or try changing the Instance Type to a different family (eg m5). See if that fixes things. Or, it might be something bad with the code.

Unfortunately, CPU levels were minimal (below 20%). I have additionally added Cloudwatch detailed instance tracing and open telemetry to see what happens inside the system. Still, all the API requests and memory usage seem tobe normal except for the feature mentioned above (File Handling) being unresponsive and the request does not resolve at all. But I saved some os levels stats and updated the question with it now.
